# how can I remove some numbers at the end of line in a text file

Tags: linux

I have a text file which contains a series of same line except at the end.
eg

`lesi-1-1500-1`

lesi-1-1500-2

lesi-1-1500-3

how can I remove the last number? it goes upto 250

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to change in the file itself

```
sed -i 's/[0-9]\+$//' /path/to/file
```

or

```
sed 's/[0-9]\+$//' /path/to/file > /path/to/output
```

see [example](https://sed.js.org/?gist=f11092a5efb9b492d744c1d878dc1c2a)

Comment: Hi, Thank you it worked, just for curiosity is there a way to reverse it like now I wanna add the number My problem has been solved just asking for curiosity Thanks a million

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Awk by breaking it into fields.

```
echo "lesi-1-1500-2" > foo.txt
echo "lesi-1-1500-3" >> foo.txt

cat foo.txt | awk -F '-' '{print $1 "-" $2 "-" $3 }'
```

The `-F` switch allows us to set the delimiter which is `-`. Then we just print the first three fields with `-` for formatting.